# apache hive cannot connect to derby:metastore_db although ij from derby can

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I am setting up a hive on hadoop cluster on three machines. The hadoop (2.7.1) and derby (10.11) runs fine:

```
hduser@master:~$ ij
ij version 10.11
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true';
ij> select * from a;
ID
-----------

0 rows selected
ij>
```

but hive complains:

```
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true , username = APP. Terminating connectio pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
...
```

environmental variables:

```
# Java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk

# derby

export DERBY_HOME=/usr/local/derby
export PATH=$PATH:$DERBY_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar

# Hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"


# hive

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.
```

hive-site.xml has only this property in the config:

```
  <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
     <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true </value>
     <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore </description>
  </property>
```

what's going on?

Comment: change it to mysql, postgres or oracle. Derby will crash.

Comment: I will, I just need to test the IAAS provider (or multiple providers) and thought I fix that derby thing for good.. Somehow would be nice to understand why it crashes..

Comment: derby is not recommended for hive's metastore. It just stores the data in files and it will crash when multiple users try to access hive.

Comment: got it. Startet installing postgres. Out of curioucity it would be nice to debug and fix the derby part. Cause it won't let me sleep if I won't fix it (event if I'll never use it again :))

Comment: @AmalGJose: I successfully worked-arround the problem by replacing derby with postgres, thanks for the tip. It still would be cool to solve that bloody derby issue :)

Comment: I could not get it to work either.  So switched to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar
```

but you also said:

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
```

Thus you gave a JDBC Connection URL for the Client/Server configuration of Derby, but the CLASSPATH you provided was for the Embedded configuration of Derby.

And thus you received the error:

```
No suitable driver found
```

You can either change your CLASSPATH, or you can change your JDBC Connection URL.

If you want to use the Client/Server configuration of Derby, switch your CLASSPATH to say:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyclient.jar
```

since you need the JDBC client driver for this configuration.

If you want to use the Embedded configuration of Derby, leave your CLASSPATH alone and change your JDBC Connection URL to say:

```
jdbc:derby:metastore_db;create=true
```

To learn more about the different Derby configurations, read here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgsquck70629.html

Comment: thanks for the post. Unfortunatelly I get the same error. I've started the derby server with: `startNetworkServer -h localhost -p 1527`.  `echo $CLASSPATH` returns `:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.`, connection with ij works: `ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true';
ij>`, hive continues to complain with: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true`

Comment: Hive is being unable to find derbyclient.jar. Perhaps Hive has its own way of controlling the CLASSPATH? Possibly you can run Hive with -verbose:class? Possibly there is more information available in your exception chain: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Oh! You said that your Hive cluster has multiple machines. Possibly you are only configuring the CLASSPATH for one of those machines, and the error is coming from a different one?

Comment: Or perhaps Hive is seeing the CLASSPATH value correctly on each machine, but you haven't created the /usr/local/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar file on all of the machines in your cluster?

Comment: theoretically derby (and hive) should be installed only on the master, at the end of the day hive centrally determines the plan for the query and then issues hadoop jobs to compute it.. Well, at least there's no hive on other machienes (and if derby is replaced with postgres, everything works)

Comment: OK, sorry. I still think it's a CLASSPATH problem, but it sounds like a complex environment that you'll have to dig into.

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing this error when I opened spark-shell session in another terminal tab, when there was already an open session in different terminal tab. Closing this old terminal tab, and starting spark-shell session again in current tab fixed the issue.